# Facebook App QueryString

Tags: facebook, query-string, facebook-apps

Up until recently our FB app was passing QueryString parameters that we used to identify app users and provide them with their data through the app. Now it just has the RAW URL without the parameters.

Did Facebook change something regarding apps? Is there something I have to do in our app?

Answer (score 0):

Hi are you talking about the page link? you can get this by using FQL

eq https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+page_id,+page_url,+fan_count,+website,+name,+username,+founded,+company_overview,+mission,+pic+FROM+page+WHERE+page_id=  facebookPageId &access_token= accessToken

paste this into your browser to see a live example https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+name%2C+fan_count+FROM+page+WHERE+page_id+%3D+19292868552

Comment: actually I we were using Request.QueryString for 2 values, "qUID" - username & "qPH" - phone number. Our site is using ASP.Net, and in the 'Page_Load' event we try to get these 2 values. Until recently this was working for us. Your suggestion about the FQL is interesting, I will see if I can use this and report back, thanks for the suggestion.